# does IE not pass url params to a js script?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, parameters, internet-explorer-8

I have searched here and google for this. Found some other interesting stuff, but nothing specifically relevant.

Scenario:

```
----html page----
...
<script src="/scripts/jsFile.php?v=246" type="text/javascript"></script>
...


----jsFile.php----
<?php
$v=(int)$_GET['v'];
if (!$v) {
    echo "no version";
}
?>
```

All browsers pass the "v" parameter to the script **except** for IE 8, specifically:

- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2
- Wget/1.9+cvs-stable (Red Hat modified)

and maybe a couple of others. They do not pass the query string at all.

#### Why does IE not pass the query string parameter to the php file called as a script?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Odd. Works fine for me in IE8. Specifically: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)` (a fairly outdated IE8/XP VM I use for testing)

Comment: Enable developer tools and look at the request. Check specifically to see if the variable is being sent with the correct name etc.

You could also var_dump( $_REQUEST ); on the server side to see exactly what you received.

Comment: Sorry, no such bug exists. There's something wrong with your setup. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't get notified - but thanks for all the comments. See my responses to vantrung below. It's not at my end, it's other users' browsers. I can't replicate this at my end either.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you tested your code against all of these browsers: IE6,IE7,Chrome,FF,Opera & Safari.

And did you use this command at the first line of "jsFile.php":

```
header("Content-Type:text/javascript");
```

I've done exactly the same stuff in asp and everything works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks vantrung. I'm looking at error logs, triggered by jsFile.php when there is no query string. The only browsers that trigger the errors (don't pass the query string) are IE 8 and wget. The full spectrum of browsers use the site.

Comment: The header is irrelevant, as it's what is being passed to jsFile.php in the query string that matters - before any headers are sent back. It is also the case for cssFile.php (a css file served by a php script).